# ngTable pagination with loadmore option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I am using angular's ngTable plugin for listing data with pagination. By Pagination I mean Initially the listview should have 20 items followed with a "loadMore" button. Once the user clicks on "loadMore", it should display 10 items followed with again a "loadMore button".For E.g, The total if say is 50 then initially the data would be 20, then would list 10 on each time "loadMore" is clicked.

I have gone through the [demo](http://ng-table.com/#/demo/1-2) but wasn't able to find a convincing solution for my use case. Can you guys please help me out on this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Attaching an image below for the use case reference :-
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an answer which turned out to be pretty easy. All I needed to do was to send an iterated count to the params.count() method. Attaching code for reference.

```
       <button type="button" ng-if="params.count()<params.total()" ng-click="params.count(params.count()+10)" class="btn btn-default">More</button>
```

**10**  being the count that I wanted to show on every click of the button,while 20 being the initial displayed items. Thanks